# C#, counter reset when a condition becomes true

Tags: c#, loops, for-loop, if-statement

I have 2 counters called a1count and b1count.
The part of the code is used to control a stepper motor.
Whenever the motor driver returns a 1, it means that a rotation cycle is complete and a1count is incremented.
During the cycle, if for some reason the motor could not complete the spin(fail condition), the driver returns a 0, and b1count is incremented.

Now Im trying to create a consecutive fail condition count called c1count which will pop-up a messagebox if say suppose b1count reaches 10. If c1count <= 10 then a messagebox pops up notifying the error. However, if in between those 10 counts, a1count is incremented then I want to reset c1count to 0, ans start counting to 10 again if b1count reaches 10 consecutively without a1count increment.

This is what I have now :

```
public int a1count = 0;
public int b1count = 0;
public int c1count=0;

if (ethernetIPforSLCMicroCom1.Write("N7:70") == 1)
{    
    a1count += 1;        
}
else if (ethernetIPforSLCMicroCom1.Write("N7:70") == 0)
{                   
    b1count += 1;                   
}

   /* Im trying to create a consecutive fail condition count called c1count 
    which will pop-up a messagebox if say suppose b1count reaches 10. 
    If c1count <= 10 then a messagebox pops up notifying the error. 
    However, if in between those 10 counts, a1count is incremented then 
    I want to reset c1count to 0, ans start counting to 10 again if 
    b1count reaches 10 consecutively without a1count increment.*/

c1count = b1count;
if (c1count <= 10)
{                    
    MessageBox.Show("Consecutive Rejection Occured);
    ethernetIPforSLCMicroCom1.Write("B3:11/6", "1");                   
}
```

Please help!!

Comment: Show your a minimal viable code example.. this sounds kind of basic as it stands but its im possbile to give you an answer from that

Comment: You've written the logic of your program in the question. Write it as `//comments` in a c# class, then put code underneath the comments - we pseudocode complex algorithms using the language we natively think in (e.g. English) and then translate to C# because it's sensible - like writing an essay plan before writing an essay

Comment: dont append code in the comments. look at that code and tell us if you think it is readable. please use the edit feature and edit your question

Comment: You explained it yourself: Just set c1count to 0 whenever the a1count is increased. Your code in the comment is really hard to read, but it doesnt seem to show the needed code anyway. Show your code where you have the loops

Comment: Sorry...I have edited the main question. Im unable to find a way to reset c1 once a1 increment before c1 reaches 10.

Comment: Ok my question now is: Why do you set c1count to b1count? When you want to reset it it should be set to 0. And that would be the wrong place to reset it. Remember you only want to reset it whenever a1count is increased and not after either b1count or a1count.

Comment: Because b1count is the actual fail count. So im copying b1count to c1count and then checking if it reaches 10. So that when its reset, only c1count is reset and not the actual fail count which is b1. I have initially declared c1count as 0. But Im unable to find a way to reset c1 once a1 increment before c1 reaches 10

Comment: But like that it doesnt matter if you reset c1count, as you always copy the value of b1count. I suppose you want b1count as the "overall fails" counter? Then i would suggest the following: Increase c1count everytime you increase b1count (so when 0 is returned). Remove `c1count = b1count;`. Reset c1count to 0 everytime a1count is increased (so when 1 is returned). Now it will still show a message if you reached 10 consecutive fails, the counter will reset when a1count is increased (so a rotation cycle is completed) and b1counter sill counts the maximum fails that occur during the process

Comment: Yes...that was the solution. Thanks TheSkimek. Got it working. :)

Answer (score -3, accepted):

I'm not very clear on what you mean do you want it like this?

```
public int a1count = 0;
public int b1count = 0;
public int c1count=0;

if (ethernetIPforSLCMicroCom1.Write("N7:70") == 1)
{    
    a1count++; 
    c1count = 0;   
}
else if (ethernetIPforSLCMicroCom1.Write("N7:70") == 0)
{                   
    b1count++;
    c1count++;                  
}


if (c1count > 0 && c1count <= 10)
{                    
    MessageBox.Show("Consecutive Rejection Occured);
    ethernetIPforSLCMicroCom1.Write("B3:11/6", "1");                   
}
```

Comment: Please write what you are doing at this code.  it will help much more people for undestand this answer not jus the guy who asks.

Comment: haha...perfect. I did'nt knew there could be such a simple solution to this. I've been breaking my head with while and for loops since morning to accomplish this. Thanks Vladimir lazar.